# how to compare and match the array list in android

Tags: android, arraylist, compare

I'm new to Android.

I am facing problem with array list.The problem is,

My arrays are string array list. 
What i need is?  I have two array list. QtnsArraylist1 contains 4 elements(4 questions) and AnsArraylist2 contains 16 elements( 16 Answers, for each question 4 options totally 16 elements).For my first Question in QtnsArraylist1 i  have to get first 4 elements from AnsArraylist2.Similarly for 2,3,4 questions if give next button .How i can get? .

Please help me some one.

Thanks in Advance.

```
      D/TAG(910): 1
      D/TAG(910): 2
      D/TAG(910): 3
      D/TAG(910): 4
      D/TAG(910): 5
      D/TAG(910): 6
      D/TAG(910): 1
      D/TAG(910): 2
      D/TAG(910): 3
      D/TAG(910): 4
      D/TAG(910): 5
      D/TAG(910): 6
      D/TAG(910): 1
      D/TAG(910): 2
      D/TAG(910): 3
      D/TAG(910): 4
      D/TAG(910): 5
      D/TAG(910): 6
      D/TAG(910): 1
      D/TAG(910): 2
      D/TAG(910): 3
      D/TAG(910): 4
      D/TAG(910): 5
      D/TAG(910): 6
      D/TAG(910): 1
      D/TAG(910): 2
      D/TAG(910): 3
      D/TAG(910): 4
      D/TAG(910): 5
      D/TAG(910): 6
      D/AndroidRuntime(910): Shutting down VM
      W/dalvikvm(910): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception 
      (group=0x40015560)
      E/AndroidRuntime(910): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      E/AndroidRuntime(910): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 16, size 
      is 16
      E/AndroidRuntime(910):    at 
      java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
      E/AndroidRuntime(910):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
```

code

```
     protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();  
        for ( int i = 0,j = 0; i < ques1.size(); i++) {
            String s1 = ques1.get(i).toString();
            Log.d("TAG", "1");
            TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt); 
            txtque.setText(s1);
            Log.d("TAG", "2");
            btn_practicerg =(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdgroup);
            Log.d("TAG", "3");
            btn_practice1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RB1);
            Log.d("TAG", "4");
            btn_practice2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RB2);
            Log.d("TAG", "5");
            btn_practice3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RB3);
            Log.d("TAG", "6");
            btn_practice4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RB4);
            String s2 = answ1.get(j++);
            btn_practice1.setText(s2);
            String s3 = answ1.get(j++);
            btn_practice1.setText(s3);
            String s4 = answ1.get(j++);
            btn_practice1.setText(s4);
            String s5 = answ1.get(j++);   
            btn_practice1.setText(s5);
            //Display them
        }     
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not exactly get what is your problem. If you want to display an element from ArrayList1 followed by 4 elements of ArrayList2 then its quite simple.

```
for ( int i = 0,j = 0; i < ArrayList1.size(); i++) {
    s1 = ArrayList1.get(i);
    s2 = ArrayList2.get(j++);
    s3 = ArrayList2.get(j++);
    s4 = ArrayList2.get(j++);
    s5 = ArrayList2.get(j++);   
    //Display them
}
```

Please feel free to ask any doubts.

Try the following code

```
Log.d("TAG", "onCreate() entered");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ArrayList<String> questionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> answersList = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Initializing the arrayLists
    for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
        questionsList.add("ques" + index + 1);
    }
    for (int index = 0; index < 16; index++) {
        answersList.add("ans" + index + 1);
    }

    //Output
    for (int questionIndex = 0, answerIndex = 0; questionIndex < questionsList.size(); questionIndex++) {
        Log.d("TAG", questionsList.get(questionIndex));

        Log.d("TAG", answersList.get(answerIndex++));
        Log.d("TAG", answersList.get(answerIndex++));
        Log.d("TAG", answersList.get(answerIndex++));
        Log.d("TAG", answersList.get(answerIndex++));

    }
```

I am appending the method to set into radioBtn and textViews.

In the layout file 
set textView ids
     "@+id/questionView1"
     "@+id/questionView2" 
and so on, the radioBtns as

```
 "@+id/radioBtn1"
 "@+id/radioBtn2"
```

and so on till 16

In program

```
 for (int questionIndex = 0, answerIndex = 0; questionIndex < questionsList.size(); questionIndex++) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionView + questionIndex + 1);
        tv.setText(questionsList.get(questionIndex));

        RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioBtn + answerIndex + 1);
        rb1.setText(answersList.get(answerIndex++));

        RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioBtn + answerIndex + 1);
        rb2.setText(answersList.get(answerIndex++));

        RadioButton rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioBtn + answerIndex + 1);
        rb3.setText(answersList.get(answerIndex++));

        RadioButton rb4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioBtn + answerIndex + 1);
        rb4.setText(answersList.get(answerIndex++));


    }
```

Comment: yes same concept your right.. if first element displays from Arraylist1 for this from four elements should display from Array list2  and if increment both array same concept should run...the loop continues...

Comment: @God'sGrace Please do accept the answer if it satisfies your question . Thx

Comment: i want to display the Arraylist1 in textview and Arraylist2 in radiotext...i kept textview and radiotext while increment how to do it

Comment: textView.setText(arrayList1.get(i);  and radioButton.setText(j++)

Comment: @God'sGrace Radio Button should be placed in a Radio group in xml. Get the radio button in your program ie .java file using findViewById and then use setText()

Comment: yes i place Radiogroup in xml. Got that radiobuttons in my program. i kept like this btn_1.setText(ArrayList2.get(j)); btn_2.setText(ArrayList2.get(j));    btn_3.setText(ArrayList2.get(j));    btn_4.setText(ArrayList2.get(j));    its right...

Comment: @God'sGrace Its resource not found error, that means the view corresponding to the give id is not present in layout file. Did u save and build after creating the radioButtons in layout.

Comment: @God'sGrace The log indicates that the program could not find a view corresponding to the id specified by you. Please check if you have given the same id in your program as well as for layout.xml file.

Comment: @God'sGrace You can write Log.d("TAG", "1"); before each findViewById() stmt in your code to narrow down which view and id don't match

Comment: 01-24 13:11:05.572: E/AndroidRuntime(910): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 16, size is 16
01-24 13:11:05.572: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
01-24 13:11:05.572: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
 now im getting these errors..

Comment: @God'sGrace The problem you have now posted is occuring because the program is trying to extract 17th element (indexed 16 as indexing starts from 0) from the ArrayList2, while ArrayList2 has only 16 elements. This should not arise if you are using j++. Have you used ++j instead? That would lead to that problem. Also do check whether j was initialized to 0 and not to 1

Comment: @God'sGrace Please do initimate me when you get the output correctly by accepting the answer as  I can leave tracking the updates on this question then

Comment: @God'sGrace Yah sure .... so for the time being just increment the second of the second arrayList by adding 1 more element to it and run the program. The program may run  then and the o/p may help to figure out whats wrong

Comment: how to view this in textview and radio text help me please

Comment: @God'sGrace For that you just need to get textView n radioButton using findViewById() and then textView.setText(s) or radioBtn.setText(s);

Comment: Im not getting my array values of ques1 and answ1 its getting as q0,a0,a1,a2,a3,q1,a4,a5,a6,a7...etc..like..  what i should do to get my values

Comment: @God'sGrace I have appended it in my answer

Comment: @God'sGrace Yah i had set it as q0 a0 a1 only if you want it that way i will edit tht in my answer

Comment: @God'sGrace I have changed the portion below the comment Initializing arrayLists also to accomodate the change from q0 a0 a1 to ques 1 ans1 ans2  . It needs just a +1 over there. Take a look at the editted version

Comment: No, not like that, i should give one text view and radio buttons for 4 options,  after that if i click on next button the question and answers should increment..my data are store in ArrayList of ques1(for question) and ArrayList of answ1(for answers)....

Comment: if i had 100 questions means i should add 100 textview ahhhh...not like this i should give next button to go for question like this i need my frnd..please help me..thanks a lot in advance

Comment: @God'sGrace Ok dude then you can programmatically create and add radioBtns and textViews and then add them to layouts in a dor loop

Comment: See my code here...http://pastebin.com/kLNrAnXX  What i have code is..  Im not getting the correct question and answers. please help me in my code. what changes i should do..

Comment: Still i have problem in my increment of answers..see my code here pastebin.com/kLNrAnXX

Comment: what exactly is the problem? I will try to make the program and post it to you later. At the moment I have got some work assigned to me from my supervisor. Dude you should consider remodeling your approach and start from scratch.  Create a class test with members : String question, ArrayList<String> answers and int correctAnswerIndex .

Comment: Lets say my problem..I want to display the quiz question and answer...My question and answers are reterived from database through php.now the question are stored in a variable as ques and its array name as ques1. now the answers are stored in a variable as answ and its array name as answ1.Now i want to display the question and answers.. from arrays in a textview and options in radio text...
then the radio button should check if they select the answer...
Then i have next button if i click on next button the next question and answers should display...Likewise the loop should run...

Comment: I want to do these all in Onpost Execute()

Comment: Thats simple i will you can use the class i told for your program to modularise and improve the readability of code. I will post it later. Are you a student and is this your assignment? Or are you just trying out stuff out of interest?

Comment: trying with my interest..My frnd..Im job seeker. learning by myself.. please help me frnd..for this concept post the code for this. This should write in Onpost Execute....

Comment: ok dude i will do that i will remove the older codes when i post the new one .... keep a copy if you need the old ones

Comment: So you want the nxt question to be shown only when next button is clicked is tht right !! In that case you need only one textView and 4 radioButton. The values of the views need to be updated onClick of the button. Is tht what u waant?

Comment: This discussion is growing too long and hard to follow. However it contains good information which should be integrated into the the question or an answer. Please do that and if needed, continue the discussion in the chat!

Comment: @markus-tharkun God's Grace doesnt have enought reputation pts to be able to chat

Comment: Dude really sry i hav got some serious deadline issue ... the pgm u wanna develop is simple technically but has a bit of coding as Db is involved. The idea is get all the content from Db store it preferably in class then set the textView and radioBtns with first question and its answers. Then onClick() of a button update the contents. Its quite simple instead of setting the content with for loop you have to do it only once and update the contents in onClick() of the button. The program seems to be quite common and programs similar to it might be readily available.All you need to do is googleit

Comment: i cant understand just have my variables of arraylist and do it my frnd..in that variables only stored the questions and answers.. please help me...my question id is stored in quesid...help me frnd..

Comment: In this i should have perivous button also...please help me frnd..give ur mailid i send my full code What i have done....

Comment: @pvn vote up my question..and see this link and guide me.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701156/how-to-manage-the-radiobuttons-with-check-and-uncheck

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like,

```
int j = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < ArrayList1.size(); i++) {
    Log.d("ArrayList1", ArrayList1.get(i));
    Log.d("ArrayList2", ArrayList2.get(j));
    j++;
    Log.d("ArrayList2", ArrayList2.get(j));
    j++;
    Log.d("ArrayList2", ArrayList2.get(j));
    j++;
    Log.d("ArrayList2", ArrayList2.get(j));
    j++;
}
```

Comment: Its Showing error i used your code showing the same error see above my logcat